# See if binary files exist in subfolders

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, binary, directory

Say I have a directory structure like this:

```
+---A
|   +---A
|   \---B
+---B
|   \---A
|       \---A
+---C
|
|
[...]
```

How can I (1) crawl all folders and subfolders and (2) check if any files within those folders are binary files?

Comment: What is your definition of "binary file"?

Comment: Let's say binary means "contains bytes that are not meant to be interpreted as characters." In this case, I'm interested in finding bytecode files (e.g., `.class`) but not source files (e.g., `.java`).

Comment: technically, all files are binary... if you mean non-text, then `find . -type f -exec some_app_to_test_for_binaryness {} \;` would be one way to go.

Comment: Or `find /path/to/root -type f -name '*.class'`

Comment: `.class` is just an example. I want to test the contents, not the extension.

Comment: The best you can do is run the `file` command on each file, and see whether the word "text" is in the output. Unix doesn't have any real definition of binary vs text files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` is usually used to search directory tree.

`file -i` can be used to print files mime type information.

Give this a try :

```
find . -type f -exec file -i {} + | grep ":[^:]*executable[^:]*$" |  sed 's/^\(.*\):[^:]*$/\1/'
```

`-type f` is a filter which selects regular files: not symbolic links, not directories etc.

The `exec file -i {} +` executes `file -i` on each regular file found in the directory tree.

`file -i` is printing mime type strings:

```
file -i /bin/bash
/bin/bash: application/x-executable; charset=binary
```

`grep ":[^:]*executable[^:]*$"` selects files with a mime type string which contains `executable`

`sed 's/^\(.*\):[^:]*$/\1/'` cleans up the line in order to print only filenames, without extra mime type information.